# Count number of unique occurrences of a key value corresponding to each ID column

Tags: sql, count, db2

I have a table in DB2 as below :

```
Key     ID  SubID
Abc123  576  10
Abc123  576  12
Abc124  576  13
Abc125  577  14
Abc126  578  15
Abc127  578  16
Abc128  578  17
```

Want to create a additional count column where it counts number of unique occurrences of key value for each ID and the output should be as below

```
Key     ID  SubID Count
Abc123  576  10    2
Abc123  576  12    2
Abc124  576  13    2
Abc125  577  14    1
Abc126  578  15    3
Abc127  578  16    3
Abc128  578  17    3
```

I tried below

```
select Key, ID, SubId ,
count(Key) over (partition by Key) as count
from table
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a window function with the `DISTINCT` qualifier. You can use a scalar subquery to count the rows you want.

For example:

```
select *,
  (select count(distinct key) from t x where x.id = t.id) as cnt
from t
```

Result:

```
 KEY     ID   SUBID  CNT 
 ------- ---- ------ --- 
 Abc123  576  10     2   
 Abc123  576  12     2   
 Abc124  576  13     2   
 Abc125  577  14     1   
 Abc126  578  15     3   
 Abc127  578  16     3   
 Abc128  578  17     3
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b08557784ebb85f51adbab16d7576cd5).

Comment: Thanks for the response, this works as expected

Comment: Hello, Performance of the query is hitting very badly with the above . Anything which we can do to improve?

Comment: @datatester Adding the index `(id, key)` can help with the query above. However, the execution plan will tell you more clearly where's the bottleneck (not the solution, but at least where the problem is).

Comment: what is the approach if the above data is coming from a cte instead of a table? I tried commenting each line and check where exactly its causing the perf log , it is with scalar query . Can we use joins instead ?

Comment: @datatester The problem seems to be of a higher complexity than you initially showed. It's difficult to tell a good solution without seein the exact CTE and going into fine grain details. If the CTE is reading a high volume of rows (i.e. does not have a filtering predicate or is result of a multi-join) then the query will be a long-running one. An option I've seen working on these cases is to use a "materialized view" that represents the CTE; this view can be indexed according to the best columns (as I suggested before). You'll need to take care of refreshing the view before running the query.

Comment: Thanks for the response . Created a MQT and added indexes and top of that created a view . It did work like magic. It might not be the perfect way but does the job for me